# How to push different arrays into a single array inside For loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to push all array of objects into a single array.

For example below is a transaction array which has two different arrays:

transaction:

```
0:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
1:(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

I want something like this:

transaction:

```
0:(5) [{…}, {…}, {…},{…}, {…}]
```

I am pushing arrays inside transaction array by using a for loop, and i don't how to use concat operation inside for loop.

This below is my for loop i am push objects into transaction array:

```
for (var j = 0; j < $scope.allRecent.length; j++)
{
    if (uniqueDates[i].dates == $scope.formatDate($scope.allRecent[j].date))
    {
        tempObj.transaction.push($scope.allRecent[j].transaction)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code first, as in what have you done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply concat all the arrays. 
Try the following:

```js
var array = [[{a:1},{b:1},{c:1}], [{a:2},{b:1}]];

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    result = result.concat(array[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes this one worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To push `"abc"` to `subArray1` in this example:
`array = [[subArray1], [subArray2]]`, use `array[0].push("abc")` as `subArray1` is at index 0 of `array`

Comment: I dint get you properly??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` along with the spread operator

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
const array1 = [1,2,3,4];
const array2 = [5,6,7,8];
const array3 = [9,10];
const arr = [array1, array2, array3]
console.log(arr);

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => [...accumulator, ...currentValue];
console.log(arr.reduce(reducer));
```